# using itextsharp add image under text but over other images that have been placed

Tags: itext

Imagine a pdf with text and a application that test images over the text. 
In every test pdf is saved and the next test using same pdf.
The first time you add image under text you can see the results, next time you will try you add image under is not appear because first image cover it. 
So...exists something GetBetween or can i choose the layer that i want?
If i use GetUnderContent only first image appears and all others are hide.
If i use GetOverContent then the text is covered by image.

Comment: In a generic PDF commands for text drawing and image drawing can appear in any order. To help you, therefore, one needs more precise information (code, link to sample PDF,...)

Comment: with other words can just change the order of images that are over an pdf?

Comment: It is not trivial, in particular if the images are spread over different form xobjects, but it's possible. For a detailed answer, more precise information are required.

Comment: If the content stream of a page doesn't consist of a single reference to a single stream, but refers to an array of streams with some images in one stream and other images in another stream, and you want to add an extra stream in-between these two stream, then it's fairly simple to achieve this with iText 7. However, if none of my *if*-statements resolve to `true`, then it's not trivial. If you don't understand my *if*-statements, it will be impossible for you. An expert could do it, but if you already don't understand the *if* statements, it would take too long to explain how to do it to you.